# .net core (csproj) global.json 'projects' equivalent

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core, csproj

With .net core (project.json) I used to switch between nuget packages and source code by adding the path to source code to the `projects` field in the global.json. After I did that it would add all the projects that it could find in that path that could replace the nuget packages I referenced.

I used this feature alot because I have my own nuget packages that I use, but I want to test the changes in my other project before I publish. But once I switched to Sdk 1.0.0/VS 2017/csproj .net core that feature seemed to disappear.

The alternative is just manually adding each project, switch the references manually (since they are broken up  into project, nuget and sdk references), and then after switch it all back.

Any thoughts or advice would be great.

**UPDATE:**
Sounds like there is no equivalent in csproj (as expected), but there are msbuild workarounds for now (As of the initial VS 2017/.NET Core SDK 1.0.0 release)

Comment: Not everything is mapped to the new csproj based system.

Comment: There is a request to create a tool https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1151 - still open

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I too had gotten used to this functionality and built my workflow around it. I am still looking for a solution but I'm currently playing with the idea of using conditional logic in the csproj files. Since it's now msbuild, you can do things like this:

```
    <Choose>
    <When Condition="Exists('..\..\..\MyProject')">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\MyProject\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="MyProject" Version="1.0.0" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

This replaces the hard reference to a package with a conditional that uses a project reference if it can find the source code (in this case the directory), and a package reference if can't.

So by default you would be referencing the package, but if you want to debug one of your projects, you check it out in the location that the conditional checks, and add the project to your solution.

This way you only need to change your solution file (by adding the project) when you want to include source code, instead of rewiring all your project references.

Comment: Interseting, im not that familiar with custom msbuild logic myself, but ill try this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For others that are interested in attempting to emulate with Global.json did, I worked around this for now using a couple powershell scripts and a custom json file that mimics it. Check out my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43795974/5504245

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to do something like this in your .csproj file?

```
<Target Name="DeleteLocalCache" BeforeTargets="Pack">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)" />
  <Message Text="Cleaning $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="UpdateLocalCache" AfterTargets="Pack">        
  <Message Text="creating diretory $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)" Importance="high" />
  <MakeDir Directories="$(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)" />
  <Message Text="copying file $(PackageOutputPath)$(AssemblyName).$(version).nupkg" Importance="high" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(PackageOutputPath)$(AssemblyName).$(version).nupkg" DestinationFolder="$(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)" />
        
  <Exec Command="tar -xf $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\$(AssemblyName).$(version).nupkg -C $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)" />
  <Exec Command="certutil -hashfile $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\$(AssemblyName).$(version).nupkg SHA512 &gt; $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\temp1.txt" />
  <Exec Command="more +1 $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\temp1.txt &gt; $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\temp2.txt " />
  <Exec Command="powershell Get-Content $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\temp2.txt -First 1 &gt; $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\$(AssemblyName).$(version).nupkg.sha512" />
  <Exec Command="del /f $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\temp1.txt" />
  <Exec Command="del /f $(NugetPackageRoot)$(PackageId.ToLower())\$(version)\temp2.txt" />
</Target>
```

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6579

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?