# Adding source of a nuget package to the solution

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I have a project that consumes a NuGet package from a private NuGet feed. I also have a source code of that package in a separate project/solution. When I work on the project I want to be able to, temporarily add the mentioned source code of the package to the solution, so i can work on changes in both the project and nuget package simultaneously.

In Visual Studio 2015, with dotnet core and project.json/global.json I could add the NuGet package to the project and then modify the global.json to include the source from the disk.

```
global.json:
{
   "projects" : [ "src", "../<path_to_external_source>/src" ]
}
```

That would, temporarily, change the reference to the project on disk. Before pushing to the build server, I'd just remove one line from global.json and remove projects from solution.

In Visual Studio 2017 and csproj based dotnet core I cant't seem to get that functionality. I have to remove the nuget package, add source code manually through "add/existing project" to solution, then manually add reference instead removed NuGet references. Then reverse all that before pushing to build server.

It's especially problematic when solution has several projects consuming the NuGet package, and I need to go thorugh that process with every one of them.

Is there a way to reproduce the functionality of global.json in VS17?

Comment: It was mentioned in one of the asp.net community standups that this feature was removed when switching to csproj and that they are planning on bringing it back at some point. They mentioned that David Fowler had a prototype of this working with csproj but I was never able to find any information on it. Here is the github issue for tracking the progress: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1151

Comment: Here are a few people that have found temporary workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723021/vs-2017-reference-local-projects-by-filepath-like-using-global-json-in-vs-2015/43795974#43795974 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773815/net-core-csproj-global-json-projects-equivalent